# Git bash activate error that still remains even after using clear and cls

Tags: runtime-error, git-bash, canactivate

I used the activate command on gitbash and found an error and now the error appears anytime I open gitbash. I have tried clear and even resetting to no avail

I tried using clear and cls to erase the error completely but it hasnt worked yet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.